# Not seeing insert options for user

Tags: security, templates

I'm trying to set up a new set of users with roles.  I have them members of a couple of different roles that inherit from sitecore roles, including Author, Designer, Sitecore Client Designer and Sitecore Client Authoring.  The user also has been granted create access to all the items within a subfolder, but clicking on any of those items shows a menu with an insert item at the top but when clicking on it, it does nothing - it doesn't present a submenu of the insert options (which I've set for in the _Standard Values item for the template.

Comment: Have you verified security is set correctly using the Access Viewer?

Comment: Yes, when I look at the access viewing it appears the given user shoul have full rights for the folder in question...

Comment: If you enable standard fields on the folder and look at the Insert Options field, does it show the templates you expect?

Comment: Have you also given permissions to those templates? Please check whether role has Read or Write access to those templates

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, I had removed permissions to Templates for one of the roles for the user because I didn't want them accessing Templated directly in from the content editor, but turns out once I gave them access the insert options became available and they still didn't have access to the Templates node, which is what I wanted.